# How to mask values in data grid?

Tags: c#, data-masking

I have SSN column in data grid and i want to mask it like `*****1234` this. But when user type type SSN it should not mask it. Is there any way to mask cell in data grid.

Comment: So these data grid cells must be editable?

Comment: Yes this must be editable.

Answer (score 2):

I only know one way to do this, though there may be a simpler one*. You can host custom editing control in your datagridview cells. This contor only appears while you are editing the cell, and the value of the cell is visible otherwise. You can read more about this here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx

You can implement this in a way, that the cell itself holds only the masked value, and the editing control holds the full value.

---

*There is indeed a simpler one, see [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2505390/vincent)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302056/how-to-mask-values-in-data-grid/28302334#28302334).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an event handler for the `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView`. For example like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() != "SSN")
    {
        if (!(dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellInEditMode && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == e.RowIndex && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == e.ColumnIndex))
        {
            e.Value = "****1234";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you loose the value this way?

Comment: No. And when you start editing the cell, the "real" value is shown.

Comment: Oh, you are handling the `CellFormatting` event. Cool! I did not know this.

Comment: In which version this event is available i cannot see it.

Comment: From 2.0 to 4.6. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This event is available in data grid view not in data grid.